# In redis how to get the value of the particular key?

Tags: node.js, redis

In my node application i'm using redis DB to store the data.While getting the stored value using key i'm not getting the expected output.

```
var redis=require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var pageContent={a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"};
//client.set('A',pageContent);//here i'm setting the value
client.get('A',function(err,res){
 if(!err){
   Object.keys(res).forEach(function(k){
     console.log('key is '+k + ' value is '+res[k]);
    });
   }
 else{
    console.log('error');
   }
 });
```

Above code is not giving the stored value.While looping the result i'm getting the below error

```
 TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

So i have tried res.toString(); but i'm not getting the stored value instaed of that i'm getting only [object object];

Comment: You can only store strings using `SET`. So, either you `JSON.stringify` the object when saving, and `JSON.parse` it when reading, *or* you store it as a hash using [`HMSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) and [`HGETALL`](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall).

Comment: @LinusGThiel thank you..i will use hmset and hgetall

Comment: Cool -- you know what, I'll flesh this out as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to save an object with [`SET`](http://redis.io/commands/set). In redis, `SET` and `GET` only work with strings, so the reason you get `[object Object]` back is that's the string which was saved in redis -- the string representation of your object.

You can either serialize your objects as e.g. JSON, using `JSON.stringify` when saving, and `JSON.parse` when reading, *or* you can save your objects as redis hashes, using [`HMSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) when saving, and [`HGETALL`](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) (or [`HGET`](http://redis.io/commands/hget) / [`HMGET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmget)) when reading.

**Edit:** Note, though, that if you decide to use redis hashes, you cannot have "nested" objects -- i.e., you cannot store an object where one of the properties is an array or another object. That is,

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

is okay, while

```
{
  a: {
    b: 2
  }
}
```

is not. If you have such objects, you need another model (JSON with SET/GET works perfectly well in this case).